# Add a border to a QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

I load a QPixmap from a file. I want to add a border around the QPixmap, say 4px white on each side.

What is the fastest way to do this? Do I have to create a second larger QPixmap and draw the first into the second or is there some way to extend the existing one without scaling (I've noticed that there is a `QPixmap::transformed()` but don't know if this is suitable in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to create a second larger `QPixmap` and draw the first into the second

Yes.

> is there some way to extend the existing one without scaling

Yes. The larger pixmap will take an **unscaled** copy of the original one.

The foregoing assumes that you care about the resulting pixmap. If you don't care about it, but only care to display the pixmap on a window/widget with some border, then simply draw the border and pixmap separately using `QPainter`, OpenGL geometry, etc.