# How do I add a border to a rounded QPixmap?

Tags: qt

I'm trying to show a rounded avatar QPixMap with a white border around it. However, I have no clue as to how I could add the border... Is it even possible?

This is the function I have to draw the avatar image.

```
void AccountDropDownMenu::setAvatar(
        const QByteArray& bytes)
{
    QPixmap new_avatar;
    new_avatar.loadFromData(bytes);
    new_avatar = new_avatar.scaledToHeight(40, Qt::SmoothTransformation);


    QBitmap map(new_avatar.size());
    map.fill(Qt::color0);

    QPainter painter(&map);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::color1);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::white, 10));
    painter.drawRoundedRect(
            m_avatar_label->x(),
            m_avatar_label->y(),
            new_avatar.width(),
            new_avatar.height(),
            45,
            45);

    new_avatar.setMask(map);

    avatar_label->setPixmap(new_avatar);
}
```

**Update**

Thanks to dtech I was able to get the desired output using the following updated function.... Although it's a bit pixly (the border).

```
void AccountDropDownMenu::setAvatar(
        const QByteArray& bytes)
{
    QPixmap new_avatar;
    new_avatar.loadFromData(bytes);
    new_avatar = new_avatar.scaledToHeight(40, Qt::SmoothTransformation);


    QBitmap map(new_avatar.size());
    map.fill(Qt::color0);

    QPainter painter(&map);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::color1);
    painter.drawRoundedRect(
                QRectF(
                    avatar_label->x(),
                    avatar_label->y(),
                    new_avatar.width(),
                    new_avatar.height()),
                40,
                40);
    new_avatar.setMask(map);

    QPainter painter2(&new_avatar);
    painter2.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter2.setPen(QPen(Qt::white, 1));
    painter2.drawRoundedRect(
                QRectF(
                    avatar_label->x(),
                    avatar_label->y(),
                    new_avatar.width(),
                    new_avatar.height()),
                40,
                40);

    avatar_label->setPixmap(new_avatar);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a border to a QPixmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865524/add-a-border-to-a-qpixmap)

Comment: Catch 22 - all pixmaps are non-rounded rectangles ;)

Comment: An answer/solution belongs as an answer, not in the question. Please edit it out and move it to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt you draw fills with a brush, but outlines are drawn with a `QPen`.

I haven't used `QPainter` in a long time, but IIRC, the default pen is zero width, which would explain why you aren't getting anything -  you are not setting a pen.

Also, you don't need "another" rounded rectangle, you can apply fill and outline to the same geometry, [as demonstrated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196610/qt-drawing-a-filled-rounded-rectangle-with-border/29196812#29196812).

Update:

Your updated code sets a mask, which sets an alpha channel. That cuts away from what you already have, it could not possibly add anything. You have to paint on the pixmap. Simply use `new_avatar` as the paint device - `QPainter painter(&new_avatar);` and get rid of the rest.

Comment: I've updated  my question with the pen set but no outline appears.

Comment: @Rick you have to set the pen **before** you paint, adoy!

Comment: Still no outline haha. Although it did seem to shrink my icon by the size I specified in the pen....

Comment: I did read it, aside from filling the image with a color (this is not what I want) I seem to do the same general things.

Comment: No, the background is transparent for the label itself, and behind that it's black.

Comment: Thanks, the mask is there so that it makes the QPixmap rounded (like cuts out the corners). But I was able to just add another painter onto the resulting pixmap and add the outline like that... Although it's a bit pixly. Updated with the new function.